# DATALENGTH in SQL Server returns 1 BYTE for multibyte character

Tags: sql, sql-server, datalength, multibyte-characters

I need to check in SQL Server how many bytes are used by a value. According to the documentation the [`DATALENGTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function should return values in bytes, but it seems that's not the case. Oracle and Postgres work as expected.

```
-- Oracle, 3 bytes
SELECT LENGTHB('和');    
-- Postgres, 3 bytes
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH('和'); 
**-- SQL Server, 1 byte
SELECT DATALENGTH('和');**
```

Should I use another function?

Comment: '和' is a varchar and varchars reports datalengths = characters count. You probably want N'和'. If you run `SELECT DATALENGTH(N'和'), '和', N'和';` you probably see what the problem is

Comment: I think it's not true. N'text is the same as CAST (text AS NVARCHAR). After the modification even "a" letter is 2 bytes character.
SELECT DATALENGTH(N'a');

Comment: Well, datalength always returns byte length, which is 1 in varchar and 2 in nvarchar's per character (unless you're working on utf8 collation which is another birdy altogether). Some weird composite characters might return more though

Comment: @siggemannen That actually depends on the chars used. The [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) section in nchar and nvarchar  (Transact-SQL) documentation clearly states "in higher Unicode ranges (65,536 to 1,114,111) one character may use two byte-pairs."

Comment: @ZoharPeled,  yeah, that's what i ment by `Some weird composite characters might return more though`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `SELECT DATALENGTH('和');` returning `1` is correct. `'和'` is very likely outside the base codepage you are using, which means that you are effectively asking for the `DATALENGTH` of `'?'`, and that does only consist of 1 byte.

*Presumably* your Postgres and Oracle environments are in UTF-8, where the character takes up 3 bytes. In UCS-2/UTF-16, however. the character `和` only takes up 2 bytes. When making these comparisons, you need to actually make the test *fair*; have the data type and code pages all be the same.

If you compare the `DATALENGTH`s of your string as an ANSI `varchar`, UCS-2 `nvarchar`, and a UTF-8 `varchar`, you get the values `1`, `2` and `3` respectively:

```sql
SELECT DATALENGTH('和') AS [ANSI Length],
       DATALENGTH(N'和') AS [UCS-2 Length],
       DATALENGTH(CONVERT(varchar(4),N'和' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_WS_SC_UTF8)) AS [UTF-8 Length];
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. That's because different default character set settings.

-- Oracle: AL32UTF8
SELECT *
  FROM nls_database_parameters 
 WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

--Postgres: UTF8
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;

Sql Server:
-- cp1250
SELECT default_character_set_name 
  FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
 WHERE schema_name = 'xxx'
;
-- Polish_CI_AS
SELECT collation_name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'xxxx';

Comment: You're welcome, @drk . As a note, as you may not be aware of how the site works, there is a article in the [help] on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) "Thank you" comments end up deleted, as they are seen as noise.